# How to create Python like dictionaries with Go?

Tags: go

I'm trying to make a python-like dictionary. I've tried:

```
var chunk = map[string]string{
    "code": "5000",
    "error": err,
}

var payload = map[string]string{
    "type": "response",
    "error": chunk,
}
```

I've also tried

```
    var payload = map[string]string{
    "type": "response",
    "error": {
        "code": "5000",
        "error": err,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go is a statically typed language. So you can not create dynamic maps. You defined your maps as `map[string]string` so your map key and values needs to be string.

You can use `map[string]interface{}` to use a map dynamically. But whenever you use the value you need to cast it in your desired type.

As example

```
chunk := map[string]interface{}{
    "code": "5000",
    "error": err,
    "a": 5,
    "b": 7,
}

intvalue := chunk["a"].(int)
```

Answer (score 3):

[@sadlil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39071538/1924666) gave a correct answer. But I want to add one additional case.

In python, a dictionary can be like this too

```
dict = {"key1":"value", 1: "one", "key2": 2, (1,2,3): False}
```

where not only value, but also key can be different type in a same dictionary.

If you always need a string key, this `map[string]interface{}` give appropriate answer.

But, to make more python-like-dictionary, you can also do this

```
map[interface{}]interface{}
```

Example

```
type AB struct {
    data string
}
var ab = AB{data: "data"}
var pyLikeDict = map[interface{}]interface{}{
    "key1": "value",
    1:      "one",
    "key2": 2,
    true:   "true",
    ab:     false,
}

for key, value := range pyLikeDict {
    fmt.Printf("%v -> %v\n", key, value)
}

// key1 -> value
// 1 -> one
// key2 -> 2
// true -> true
// {data} -> false
```

See in <kbd>[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cZQtf0DZhjH)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The maps you're creating are map[string]string.  You probably want map[string]interface{} instead to specify generic pointer types.

Note that you'll need some casts and syntactic sugar to coerce the *chunk and strings in there.  Play with it a bit--you'll figure it out :-)